# RNN exploding/vanishing gradient, hidden cell formulation

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I was reading a RNN paper that discuss vanishing/exploding gradient: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/pascanu13.pdf and when they present Eq. 2, they assume that 
$$
x_t = W_{rec} \sigma(x_{t-1}) + W_{in} u_t + b
$$
And
$$
x_t = \sigma(W_{rec} x_{t-1} + W_{in} u_t + b)
$$
Are two equivalent formulations.

I tried to prove they were equivalent but wasn't able to. Someone has any hints regarding that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the first as
$$
x_t = W_{rec} \sigma(x_{t-1}) + W_{in} u_t + b
$$
and the second as
$$
x'_t = \sigma(W_{rec} x'_{t-1} + W_{in} u_t + b)
$$

you can see they are equivalent when $x'_t = \sigma(x_t)$. So any function $f$ you might want to compute on $x'_t$, you can also compute it by $f(x_t') = f(\sigma(x_t))$.